# How to use 'DISTINCT ON' to query last row of duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I came across this [tutorial](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-select-distinct/) on `DISTINCT ON ()` query. To achieve the output, the following query was used:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT ON
    (bcolor) bcolor, fcolor
FROM
    t1
ORDER BY
    bcolor,
    fcolor;
```

The

[image: process]

is illustrated here where the top row of the duplicated rows are returned. However, is there a way to return the bottom of the duplicated rows instead? My use case is that multiple applications/registrations might enter and I want to query all the most recent distinct applications.

Appreciate your time, cheers!

Comment: If thats the case you can add DESC in your ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want a descending sort on the second key:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (bcolor) bcolor, fcolor
FROM t1
ORDER BY bcolor, fcolor DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a date or id columns that increments to indicate what the most recent row is, simply order by that column and add DESC to specify ordering by descending order.

```
SELECT
DISTINCT ON
registration_date, student_id, student_name
FROM
    t1
ORDER BY
    registration_date desc,
    student_id,
    student_name;
```